# Does DistributedDataParallel need the barrier in Dataloader

Tags: pytorch, distributed

I am recently reading the huggingface source code and find in https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/legacy/question-answering/run_squad.py:

There is a function load_and_cache_examples.
In the function, there are some barriers used

```
def load_and_cache_examples(args, tokenizer, evaluate=False, output_examples=False):
    if args.local_rank not in [-1, 0] and not evaluate:
        # Make sure only the first process in distributed training process the dataset, and the others will use the cache
        torch.distributed.barrier()
    input_dir = args.data_dir if args.data_dir else "."
    cached_features_file = os.path.join(
        input_dir,
        "cached_{}_{}_{}".format(
            "dev" if evaluate else "train",
            list(filter(None, args.model_name_or_path.split("/"))).pop(),
            str(args.max_seq_length),
        ),
    )

    # Init features and dataset from cache if it exists
    if os.path.exists(cached_features_file) and not args.overwrite_cache:
        logger.info("Loading features from cached file %s", cached_features_file)
        features_and_dataset = torch.load(cached_features_file)
....

   if args.local_rank == 0 and not evaluate:
        # Make sure only the first process in distributed training process the dataset, and the others will use the cache
        torch.distributed.barrier()

    if output_examples:
        return dataset, examples, features
    return dataset
```

I suppose this Dataset built here will work with the DDP model here

```
if args.local_rank != -1:
        model = torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(
            model, device_ids=[args.local_rank], output_device=args.local_rank, find_unused_parameters=True
        )
```

I am not sure whether the DDP model will load and use data for each process. Or DDP model's processes only load data from the main process (which the barrier **is blocking the other processes to fetch data**). This question can be simplified to "is DDP model requiring barrier used while building dataset?"

In the pytorch page https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel.html, I didn't find such requirements. Not sure why the barriers added here.

Comment: Want to mention, adding the barrier or not both work for me in my model. So not sure whether I should add the barrier.